# Is it possible to remove the indirection from a class?

Tags: d

I often encounter some parts of phobos that are classes, but usually I do not need polymorphism.

Like for example [Fiber](https://dlang.org/library/core/thread/fiber.html)

I would like to write

```d
Array!Fiber fibers;
```

But then the fibers should be allocated directly in the array.

I have looked at [scoped](https://dlang.org/phobos/std_typecons.html#.scoped) but it then disables the copy constructor and I am not allowed to move the types, which makes it pretty useless to me.

> it's illegal to move a class reference even if you are sure there are no pointers to it. As such, it is illegal to move a scoped object.

Edit:

Is this the correct way of allocating a class inside a struct?

```d
struct Struct(T)
if(is(T == class)){
    static immutable size = __traits( classInstanceSize, T);
    void[size] buffer;
    T t;
    alias t this;
    this(Args...)(auto ref Args args){
        import std.conv: emplace;
        t = emplace!T(buffer, args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: https://dlang.org/library/std/conv/emplace.html (make it array of void chunks and emplace into array elements).

Correct answer: you don't really want to do it in this case and it doesn't make much sense :) Most of fiber memory taken comes from stack allocation and that isn't part of `Fiber` object but allocated separately: https://github.com/D-Programming-Language/druntime/blob/master/src/core/thread.d#L4320

That means you don't benefit much from having `Fiber` instances in contiguous memory chunk as fragmentation remains. At the same time you risk a lot by hacking around class inherent polymorphic semantics and add a point of risk in your code that will need extra care/attention all the time.

Comment: This shouldn't be specific to just `Fibers`, it was more a general question.  I updated my question based on your answer.

Comment: Yes, it is correct. It still remains very fragile `@system` level code which you need to be very careful to maintain though.